# How to extract the table and it's values using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

How to extract the table and it's values using BeautifulSoup? Tried following the bs4 documentation and was having issues finding either the `class` or the `th` values. How can I explicitly get just the `{underReplicatedBlocks}` value from the entire HTML page.

```
<div class="page-header"><h1><small>Decommissioning</small></h1></div>
<small>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Node</th>
      <th>Last contact</th>
      <th>Under replicated blocks</th>
      <th>Blocks with no live replicas</th>
      <th>Under Replicated Blocks <br/>In files under construction</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {#DecomNodes}
  <tr>
    <td>{name} ({xferaddr})</td>
    <td>{lastContact}</td>
    <td>{underReplicatedBlocks}</td>
    <td>{decommissionOnlyReplicas}</td>
    <td>{underReplicateInOpenFiles}</td>
  </tr>
  {/DecomNodes}
</table>
</small>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the tr attribute in the document you are scraping is in every 3'd line then you can use this option:

```
rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2::3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no special classes for the tags you want, you're going to have to get the indices by looking at the HTML and hard code them. Look at the table, and check in which row (`<tr>`) is the required text present; similarly do it for the column.

Since it is located in the second row and third column, you'll have to use this:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
required_row = rows[1]
columns = required_row.find_all('td')
required_column = columns[2]
required_text = required_column.text
```

Or, simply:

```
required_text = table.find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')[2].text
print(required_text)
# {underReplicatedBlocks}
```